# Sum of the reciprocals of the products of primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Q. Find an upper bound for the following sum of an infinite series:

$$\sum(\frac{1}{2\times3}+\frac{1}{5\times7}+\frac{1}{11\times13}+...)$$

The denominator is a series of prime numbers.

I am aware that the sum of an infinite series of reciprocals of primes diverges, but I am told that the summation above converges.

Comment: Well, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac 1{n(n+1)}=\frac 12$ gives a start.

Comment: I wrote a small program, and the sum seems to converge to somewhere below 0.3. Can the upper bound be tighter than that?

Comment: Are you looking for an upper bound or for a way to compute the series?    It's easy to improve my bound in small ways (delete unhelpful terms like $\frac 1{3\times 4}$ and so on).  Or use it to compute the series by adding the first hundred terms of yours, then using my bound to cap the error.

Comment: It would be best if the summation can be computed.

Comment: I just gave an (easy) way to compute the series numerically.  I don't see an analytic way to compute it (which does not mean that there isn't one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another hint.  Your sum of "adjacent" prime reciprocals is obviously less than:$$\frac1 {2^2}+\frac 1 {4^2}+\frac 1 {6^2}+...=\frac 1 4.\frac {\pi^2} 6=\frac {\pi^2} {24}=0.411 (approx.)$$  With only a bit more cunning I am sure that this upper bound could be improved significantly.

Here is another much better method:  Your sum is less than the following sum:$$\frac 1 {2.3}+\frac1 {5.7}+\frac1 {11.13}+\frac1 {17.19}+\frac1 {23.25}+...+\frac1 {(6n-1)(6n+1)}+...$$  This is easily shown to be (by treating the first term alone and then the rest as a simple infinite series using the cotangent expansion): $$\frac1 6+\frac1 {12}(6-\sqrt3\pi)=0.213216826...$$  This gives a much tighter upper bound for the prime series of fractions (the first four terms are the same!).  By actual numerical calculation, the original infinite sum involving prime numbers is just a little over 0.21, slightly less than this upper bound just calculated.

Answer (score 2):

A similar sum, which also includes the other half of the products like 1/(3*5), 1/(7*11) and so on, is discussed in https://oeis.org/A210473 and I have posted estimates of that sort in a PDF file in a URL in https://oeis.org/A209329 .